# How to write regular expression for a string that starts and ends with a specific text in the same line

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to write a regular expression to search for a string that starts with 'test1' and ends with the first 'end' in the same line.

I have tried with

```
test1[^end]*end
```

But failed. Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated.

I am trying it with 'sed' and test string is:

```
test1123andendtest2456end
```

What am I trying:

```
echo 'test1123andendtest2456end'| sed -e 's/test1.*end/matrix/'
```

Result:

```
matrix
```

What do I expect:

```
matrixtest2456end
```

Comment: It depends on the tool/language you're using.

Comment: "[Positive look ahead](https://www.google.de/search?q=Positive+look+ahead)" perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
^test.*end$
```

- `^` is the begin of the line
- `test` is the literal *test*
- `.*` means zero or more of *any char*. The behaviour of the `*` *greedy* meaning it will consume as many as possible characters to fulfil the condition. This includes consuming instances of the string *end*, as long as there is one more instance of it at the end.
- `end` is the literal *end*
- `$` is the end of the line.

*Sidenote:* The greediness of the `*` operator doesn't matter in this example because the final *end* is anchored with the end of the line `$`.

---

`sed` by default is using *basic posix regular* expression. They are explained well in the [manual of `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions)

Comment: Even if not greedy, when anchoring the trailing text to the end of line, there's only one possibility, being greedy or not.

Comment: @LuisColorado Yes, that's true. However, I felt like I can explain it anyway.

Comment: I preferred to make a comment than to edit your question, because I don't feel myself votable for this contribution for sharing the answer with you.  So, if you edit the answer, probably I'll take this comment out the way.

Comment: It is not wrong, regardless of the anchoring or not. However, I've added a sidenote.

Comment: I have not said it is wrong.  Your comment uses the fact that the `*` is a greeding operator, but being greedy or not, doesn't apply, as both, the greedy operator and the nongreedy one would match that same string, because of the anchor.  This is only the point I posted, that can confuse the interpretation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^test1(.+)end$
```

If you want to try your code  : https://regex101.com/

Comment: I think the line `test1end` (with no characters in between is a valid input also, and will not be matched by that regexp, it would be better to use `^test1(.*)end$`.